# What verb form is "見えたり する" and what does it mean?

Tags: verbs

I can't find an explanation on the web and I only can guess what it means.

The context is this: 幽霊とか見えたりするのか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「[幽霊]{ゆうれい}とか[見]{み}えたりするのか？」

" Verb in [連用形]{れんようけい} + たり + する" is a very common ***informal*** phrase meaning "to do things like ~~".

It becomes even more informal and colloquial when combined with another informal word like 「とか」.

"Can you (perhaps) see ghosts and such?"

It is asking if the other person has extrasensory perception.

Answer (score 1):

The ～たり～たりする construction is used to show that the preceding actions or states are  examples among a larger list of possible actions and states. When used with a single action/state, as in your sentence, the speaker does not necessarily have other examples in mind, but is merely using the ～たりする construction to be vague and indirect.