# meaning of たりしてくれる

Tags: grammar, meaning

A young couple are cooking together and he mentions that this is special now but may become the usual in the distant future when they move in together someday and the like (こんな is referring to this dialogue), and then at the end the girlfriend remarks:

> …こんなのが当たり前になる日のこと考え**たりしてくれるん**ですね

I understand everything up to 考え but I'm confused about the たりしてくれる part. What does it mean here? I've seen grammar lessons on -てくれる and たりして but I can't make sense of either meaning in this sentence. 
Thanks

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21214/9831

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add on to Mauro's answer, the くれる part of this sentence conveys how the girlfriend thinks that it is thoughtful/caring/considerate that the boyfriend actually thinks about the day that such things will become the norm.

Why the girlfriend would think this in a positive light (as implied by くれる) is entirely dependent on context/interpretation, but one can most commonly interpret it as the girlfriend being comforted that the boyfriend thinks about their future and relationship in a concrete way. i.e. you are thinking about this for me / for our relationship (~くれる)

So in a very non-literal translation, this sentence would be "I appreciate* you contemplating about this and more^."

```
* - implied by ~くれる
^ - implied by ~たりして
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the [~たり~たりする](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n4-grammar-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A-taritari/) construction. Sometimes it's used with just one `~たりする`, meaning a non exhaustive listing, "things like ~", in `て`-form since it's followed by `くれる`.